# Windows phone - stretch image

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, scale

I want to stretch the image on the whole page.

**Fill** is not appropriate - the proportions are not saved. 
**UniformToFill** - leaves an empty space above and below.

I need to image spread over the whole page to the conservation scale.Part of the image will be clipped. How do I do this?

Comment: I think you are looking for the **Uniform** property.
Is that enough? Or it doesn't fill the screen?

Comment: Uniform does not work. Remains free space above and below. This is not the entire screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `UniformToFill` and `Fill` take the whole available space, but with different stretching behaviours. If you see empty space, that means that not the whole space is available. Maybe you placed `Margins` or set explicit `Width` and `Height` on `Image` (or placed the `Image` in a container with `Margins` or `Width`/`Height`).

Comment: Thank you. This is  work (Stretch = "UniformToFill", VerticalAlignment ="Center", HorizontalAlignment ="Center")